# output js regex group matches

Tags: regex

I have a string such as this:

```
hello [world (this is a string) with parenthesis](i'm in brackets too)
```

Using regex I'm trying to get any match contained within square brackets [...] and also get any matches within round brackets (...) Some of my strings contain just (...) and some just contain [...], others contain a mix of both, nested and separate, as in the example above.

So, the output I'm trying to reach:

```
1. [world (this is a string) with parenthesis]
2. (this is a string)
3. (i'm in brackets too)
```

I assume that 1. will be a Match Group 1 and 2&3 will be Match Group 2?

The code and regex I'm using at present is:

```
var str = "hello[world(this is a string) with parenthesis](i'm in brackets too)";
var re = /\[(.*?)\]|\((.*?)\)/g; // try and get all [] and ()

var match = re.exec(str.toString());

if (match) {
  // how do I output what are in square brackets
  // and what are in round brackets?
  // is it console.log(match[1]) for example ?? 
}
```

I'm using the | operator in my regex and I think this may impact my results. Is it stopping as soon as it hits a match and not capturing the other strings in any type of parenthesis?

The main issue I have is trying to access the matched groups - I thought that they would be in match[0] and match[1] given I'm expecting 2 groups, but when I console.log them I get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is caused by the fact that the matches you expect overlap (one may be a part of another). Thus, you just need to wrap your expression into an unanchored positive lookahead:

```
(?=\[([^\]]*)\]|\(([^)]*)\))
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM2iI3/1) (I replaced the lazy dot matching with more efficient negated character classes).

JS demo:

```js
var re = /(?=\[([^\]]*)\]|\(([^)]*)\))/g; 
var str = 'hello [world (this is a string) with parenthesis](i\'m in brackets too) ';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {   // These lines are required as
        re.lastIndex++;               // the regex matches an empty string
    }
    if (m[1]) {                      // The capture groups
       res.push(m[1]);               // hold the text we need
    } else {
      res.push(m[2]);
    }
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```